# How to place minor ticks on symlog scale?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use the symlog scale of matplotlib to cover a large ranges of parameters extending both into positive and negative direction. Unfortunately, the symlog-scale is not very intuitive and probably also not very commonly used. Therefore, I'd like to make the used scaling more obvious by placing minor ticks between the major ticks. On the log part of the scale, I want to place ticks at [2,3,…,9]*10^e where `e` is the nearby major tick. Additionally, the range between 0 and 0.1 should be covered with evenly placed minor ticks, which would be 0.01 apart. I tried using the [matplotlib.ticker API](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/ticker_api.html) to arrive at such ticks using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator, AutoLocator

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
y = x

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.yscale('symlog', linthreshy=1e-1)

yaxis = plt.gca().yaxis
yaxis.set_minor_locator(LogLocator(subs=np.arange(2, 10)))

plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, this does not produce what I want:

[image]

Note that there are way to many minor ticks around 0, which are probably due to the `LogLocator`. Furthermore, there are no minor ticks on the negative axis.

No minor ticks appear if I use and `AutoLocator` instead. The `AutoMinorLocator` does only support evenly scaled axes. My question thus is how to achieve the desired tick placement?

Comment: I did something simpler than the accepted answer that might work for an example I needed. I used the ax.set_xticks method

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Digging a little bit deeper into the issue, I noticed that it will be hard to come up with a general solution. Luckily, I can assume some constraints on my data and a custom made class was therefore enough to solve the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import Locator


class MinorSymLogLocator(Locator):
    """
    Dynamically find minor tick positions based on the positions of
    major ticks for a symlog scaling.
    """
    def __init__(self, linthresh):
        """
        Ticks will be placed between the major ticks.
        The placement is linear for x between -linthresh and linthresh,
        otherwise its logarithmically
        """
        self.linthresh = linthresh

    def __call__(self):
        'Return the locations of the ticks'
        majorlocs = self.axis.get_majorticklocs()

        # iterate through minor locs
        minorlocs = []

        # handle the lowest part
        for i in xrange(1, len(majorlocs)):
            majorstep = majorlocs[i] - majorlocs[i-1]
            if abs(majorlocs[i-1] + majorstep/2) < self.linthresh:
                ndivs = 10
            else:
                ndivs = 9
            minorstep = majorstep / ndivs
            locs = np.arange(majorlocs[i-1], majorlocs[i], minorstep)[1:]
            minorlocs.extend(locs)

        return self.raise_if_exceeds(np.array(minorlocs))

    def tick_values(self, vmin, vmax):
        raise NotImplementedError('Cannot get tick locations for a '
                                  '%s type.' % type(self))


x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
y = x

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.yscale('symlog', linthreshy=1e-1)

yaxis = plt.gca().yaxis
yaxis.set_minor_locator(MinorSymLogLocator(1e-1))

plt.show()
```

This produces

[image]

Note that this method only places ticks between major ticks. This will become noticeable if you zoom and pan into the image. Furthermore, the linear threshold has to be supplied to the class explicitly, since I found no way to easily and robustly read it off the axis itself.

Comment: Could you open a PR into upstream to add this to the mpl codebase?

Comment: To get the threshold from the data in the plot directly, I'm using:

`LN = matplotlib.lines.Line2D
threshold = 10**min([int(round(np.log(np.min(np.abs(line.get_xdata() if isinstance(line,LN) else line.get_offsets())))))-2 for line in ax.lines+ax.collections])`

Answer (score 6):

The OPs solution works well, but tick marks do not get produced at the edges of the axes if they are not multiples of the linear threshold values. I've hacked the OPs `MinorSymLogLocator()` class to give the following (which fills in the edges by adding temporary major tick locations when setting the minor tick locatoin):

```
class MinorSymLogLocator(Locator):
    """
    Dynamically find minor tick positions based on the positions of
    major ticks for a symlog scaling.
    """
    def __init__(self, linthresh, nints=10):
        """
        Ticks will be placed between the major ticks.
        The placement is linear for x between -linthresh and linthresh,
        otherwise its logarithmically. nints gives the number of
        intervals that will be bounded by the minor ticks.
        """
        self.linthresh = linthresh
        self.nintervals = nints

    def __call__(self):
        # Return the locations of the ticks
        majorlocs = self.axis.get_majorticklocs()

        if len(majorlocs) == 1:
            return self.raise_if_exceeds(np.array([]))

        # add temporary major tick locs at either end of the current range
        # to fill in minor tick gaps
        dmlower = majorlocs[1] - majorlocs[0]    # major tick difference at lower end
        dmupper = majorlocs[-1] - majorlocs[-2]  # major tick difference at upper end

        # add temporary major tick location at the lower end
        if majorlocs[0] != 0. and ((majorlocs[0] != self.linthresh and dmlower > self.linthresh) or (dmlower == self.linthresh and majorlocs[0] < 0)):
            majorlocs = np.insert(majorlocs, 0, majorlocs[0]*10.)
        else:
            majorlocs = np.insert(majorlocs, 0, majorlocs[0]-self.linthresh)

        # add temporary major tick location at the upper end
        if majorlocs[-1] != 0. and ((np.abs(majorlocs[-1]) != self.linthresh and dmupper > self.linthresh) or (dmupper == self.linthresh and majorlocs[-1] > 0)):
            majorlocs = np.append(majorlocs, majorlocs[-1]*10.)
        else:
            majorlocs = np.append(majorlocs, majorlocs[-1]+self.linthresh)

        # iterate through minor locs
        minorlocs = []

        # handle the lowest part
        for i in xrange(1, len(majorlocs)):
            majorstep = majorlocs[i] - majorlocs[i-1]
            if abs(majorlocs[i-1] + majorstep/2) < self.linthresh:
                ndivs = self.nintervals
            else:
                ndivs = self.nintervals - 1.

            minorstep = majorstep / ndivs
            locs = np.arange(majorlocs[i-1], majorlocs[i], minorstep)[1:]
            minorlocs.extend(locs)

        return self.raise_if_exceeds(np.array(minorlocs))

    def tick_values(self, vmin, vmax):
        raise NotImplementedError('Cannot get tick locations for a '
                          '%s type.' % type(self))
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a simpler approach, which might be applicable:

I used the ax.set_xticks method with an output from the function below

```
def gen_tick_positions(scale_start=100, scale_max=10000):

    start, finish = np.floor(np.log10((scale_start, scale_max)))
    finish += 1
    majors = [10 ** x for x in np.arange(start, finish)]
    minors = []
    for idx, major in enumerate(majors[:-1]):
        minor_list = np.arange(majors[idx], majors[idx+1], major)
        minors.extend(minor_list[1:])
    return minors, majors
```

For the OP's example, you could infer the linear region from ax.get_yticks() (i.e. the values that are around zero and not a factor of 10 different 0-1/10)

```
y_ticks = ax.get_yticks()
total_scale = list(y_ticks)

zero_point = total_scale.index(0.0)
post_zeroes = np.log10(total_scale[zero_point+1:])
first_log = []
for idx, value in enumerate(post_zeroes[:-1]):
    if 1.005 > post_zeroes[idx+1] - value > 0.995:
        first_log = total_scale[idx + zero_point]
```

This then gives you a start value to put into the function above, with the `scale_max` being whatever you like, such as `total_scale[-1]`.

You can use the positive and negative regions of first_log to generate the linear ticks, and then merge the lists.

```
lin_ticks = list(np.linspace(first_log * -1, first_log, 21))
pos_log_ticks_minors, pos_log_ticks_majors = gen_tick_positions(first_log, scale_max)
neg_log_ticks_minors = [x * -1 for x in pos_log_ticks_minors]
neg_log_ticks_majors = [x * -1 for x in pos_log_ticks_majors]

final_scale_minors = neg_log_ticks_minors + lin_ticks + pos_log_ticks_minors

The merged list can then be passed into e.g.

ax.set_yticks(final_scale_minors, minor=True)
```

Though it does occur to me that you don't need to read the linear threshold off the plot, or from the axis, because it's specified as an argument when you apply "symlog".

Answer (score 0):

Just some additions to David's answer, addressing what also Matt highlighted.
Note that class matplotlib.scale.SymmetricalLogScale now also has a sub argument for this, although doesn't really do outside and within the threshold. Please comment if you have suggestions and corrections.

```
        majorlocs = self.axis.get_majorticklocs()
        # my changes to previous solution
        # this adds one majortickloc below and above the axis range
        # to extend the minor ticks outside the range of majorticklocs
        # bottom of the axis (low values)
        first_major = majorlocs[0]
        if first_major == 0:
            outrange_first = -self.linthresh
        else:
            outrange_first = first_major * float(10) ** (- np.sign(first_major))
        # top of the axis (high values)
        last_major = majorlocs[-1]
        if last_major == 0:
            outrange_last = self.linthresh
        else:
            outrange_last = last_major * float(10) ** (np.sign(last_major))
        majorlocs = np.concatenate(([outrange_first], majorlocs, [outrange_last]))
```

then countinue with David'answer...